# Appending a trace and a data figure

Tags: python, append, plotly, scatter-plot

I would like to append a line trace with multiple lines trace

```
Ropefig = py.tools.make_subplots(rows=2, cols=1, shared_xaxes=True)

trace_Movt = go.Scatter( x=dfs.index + datetime.timedelta(hours=8), y=dfs['pazlm1'], mode='lines',connectgaps=True, line=dict(width=1.0,color='purple'), opacity=1, showlegend=False,hoverinfo = 'y+x')
Ropefig.append_trace(trace_Movt,1,1)
[![enter image description here][1]][1]


# Adding rope traces
trace_Rope1 = go.Scatter(x= dfs.index + datetime.timedelta(hours=8), y=dfs['rope1'],name='rope1',mode='lines',connectgaps=True, line=dict(width=1.0,color='red'), opacity=1, showlegend=True,hoverinfo = 'y+x')
trace_Rope2 = go.Scatter(x= dfs.index + datetime.timedelta(hours=8), y=dfs['rope2'],name='rope2',mode='lines',connectgaps=True, line=dict(width=1.0,color='blue'), opacity=1, showlegend=True,hoverinfo = 'y+x')
trace_Rope3 = go.Scatter(x= dfs.index + datetime.timedelta(hours=8), y=dfs['rope3'],name='rope3',mode='lines',connectgaps=True, line=dict(width=1.0,color='green'), opacity=1, showlegend=True,hoverinfo = 'y+x')                   
trace_Rope4 = go.Scatter(x= dfs.index + datetime.timedelta(hours=8), y=dfs['rope4'],name='rope4',mode='lines',connectgaps=True, line=dict(width=1.0,color='brown'), opacity=1, showlegend=True,hoverinfo = 'y+x')
trace_Rope5 = go.Scatter(x= dfs.index + datetime.timedelta(hours=8), y=dfs['rope5'],name='rope5',mode='lines',connectgaps=True, line=dict(width=1.0,color='orange'), opacity=1, showlegend=True,hoverinfo = 'y+x')
trace_Rope6 = go.Scatter(x= dfs.index + datetime.timedelta(hours=8), y=dfs['rope6'],name='rope6',mode='lines',connectgaps=True, line=dict(width=1.0,color='purple'), opacity=1, showlegend=True,hoverinfo = 'y+x')                   

trace_all_Rope = [trace_Rope1,trace_Rope2,trace_Rope3,trace_Rope4,trace_Rope5,trace_Rope6]

Ropefig.append_trace(trace_all_Rope,2,1)

py.offline.plot(Ropefig, filename=strFilename + '_' + plot_name + '.html')
```

But I get an error of Invalid element(s) received for the 'data' property

Is there any way that I can achieve this in plotly.

From the image below I want to put 'rope1' and 'rope2' in one figure and 'pazlm1' in another figure and then I want to append both of them.

[image: Screenshot of my dataset]

Comment: In which line does the error occur. And what does your datasource look like? Please provide some sample data.

Comment: Towards the end Ropefig.append_trace(trace_all_Rope,2,1) and I am not sure how to send the sample data

Comment: A screenshot of your dataframe is better than nothing.

Comment: Added a screenshot of my dataset and added additional decription

Comment: I excluded some columns , please take note.

Comment: `pazlm1` is a boolean, and the rest seem to be timeseries. So apparently you'd like to see all timeseries on one plot, and  `pazlm1` in another next to it? Or what?

Comment: Yes all rope are float and pazlm1 is boolean and I want to put all of them in one figure

Comment: I want to see all rope column and pazlm1 in the same figure